# Is it possible to always use the coverage option "Use tracing"

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

I would like to use the "Use tracing" coverage option always, instead of having to go into "Run configurations" and set the coverage option there, for every class or method that I run a test on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the run config template: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#templates